# How exactly does the human penis grow during puberty?

Tags: human-biology

I learned that testosterone triggers the growing process, but I was unable to find anything else about this process. What exactly happens inside the penis during this period that causes it to grow? How does its structure change when it grows?

Comment: Welcome. Can you add your own research efforts? The question is broad and there should be a lot of info out there on the internet

Comment: Sorry if I don't know how to ask correctly yet. Does Googling the questions I asked and paraphrased it many times without getting anything beyond basic knowledge count as research?

Comment: Most of the results say "it just does that during puberty", or some are a little more detailed and say "testosterone causes that". I think the answer may lie in some specialized textbooks, but I didn't study biology at higher education level so I don't know what kind of books to begin reading in. Should I change the question to "Which book can I find this information in?"

Comment: https://pmj.bmj.com/content/postgradmedj/51/594/200.full.pdf. It would help to know what level of detail you're looking at. Do you want to know about the histology of the penis, the gross structure (shape/size), endocrine interactions, etc? Each of these is its own rather large field.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I see, so this is a more complicated question than I thought. If I wanted to know about how the cells and tissues structure changes, that would be histology, right?

Comment: @PennPaper yes that is my understanding. I would update your question with information about what you're specifically interested in, which appears to be how shape and composition of tissues changes over time. You might also consider migrating the question to [SE Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/).